# how to force for "Text Only" email format while fetching them from gmail server using POP3 protocol?

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, pop3, zend-mail

Hi I am using Zend_Mail pop3 client to fetch emails from gmail account problem is the content which I get is in HTML format but I want to store only text format .  There are to solution I am looking forward to

a) force my pop3 client to retrieve only text message
b) conver html into simple text i.e remove all the html tags properly .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email is either in one specific format, or its in "multipart". In every case you must download the whole email. After it, you may either retrieve the text-part (if its multipart or text), or you must parse the html-source (or just [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip-tags)), if its html-only.

[Zend_Mail_Part::getPart()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Mail_Part.html#Zend_Mail_Part%3a%3agetPart%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Whether mail is html or test is decided by the sender, not the recipient.  Sometimes mail will be "multipart" where there is both a text and html version and you can choose to view either, but basically, you get what you get.  Zend is PHP and allows plugins, so you might make use of a PHP html-to-text converter.  I've seen some code on the web.